# A recursive formula

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, recurrences

$$a_0 = 1, \ \ a_{n+1} = \  1+\frac{n *a_n}{n+a_n} , \ \ n=0,1,2,3,4,...$$

I have built the above recursive formula. Some terms of sequence are: 
1, 1, 3/2, 13/7, 73/34, 501/209, 4051/1546, 37633/13327, 394353/130922, 4596553/1441729, 58941091/17572114, 824073141/234662231,... Τhe numerators of the fractions are identical to the sequence  A000262 in OEIS encyclopedia and the denominators to the A002720. If we take n = {inf,.......,5,4,3,2,1}, ie to start from quite high and finish at 1. Let a (about 1.6768...) the last term. Then 1/(a*exp(1))  converges to: 0.21938393439552027367716377546012164903 ... that is the decimal expansion of -Ei(-1), A099285 in OEIS.

**My question is:**
How it is explained, and how does the formula relate to the above sequences?

Comment: Concerning the last one - it might help that this $a$ is given by the continued fraction$$1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{7}+\cdots}}}}}}}}}}}}}$$

Comment: The queston is not clear. What it means "to start from quite high and finish at 1"? Both sequences A000262 and A002720 are mentioned in 10 entres in OEIS, did you check them? http://oeis.org/search?q=A000262++A002720&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Comment: I will give an example in (PARI): The recursive formula is s=1+n * s/(n+s),
with initial value for s=1.
eint1(1)= 0.219383934395520273677163775460121649031
Let a(k)=s=1.0;forstep(n=k,1,-1,s=1+n * s/(n+s));return(s)

Comment: Some numerical examples:
For k=10   s=1.6767863973091431 and 1/s/exp(1)=0.2193 955304991764469019603
For k=50   s=1.6768750281592807 and 1/s/exp(1)=0.21938393439 80609892988775
For k=100  s=1.6768750281787006 and 1/s/exp(1)=0.2193839343955202 960012839
For k=1000 s=1.67687502817870086844136127504172485846 and
  1/s/exp(1)= 0.219383934395520273677163775460121649031 (39 digits and more accuracy) 
We see that for higher values ​​of k, we find more accuracy in decimal placies.
So we can say that 1000 is "quite high" for a good approach.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For $n\geq 1$, let $p_n$ be the $(n+1)$-th term of [A000262](https://oeis.org/A000262), and let $q_n$ be $n$-th term of [A002720](https://oeis.org/A002720). Then, according to the description of these two sequences (more precisely by the contributions of Dennis P. Walsh and Paul Berry)
$$p_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k}k!\qquad\text{and}\qquad
q_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}^2k!\ .$$
We derive some identities. First,
\begin{align}p_{n+1}-q_{n+1}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k}\binom{n}{k}k!-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2k!\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\binom{n+1}{k}-\binom{n}{k}\right)\binom{n}{k}k!\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n}{k}k!\\[6pt]
&=n\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(k-1)!\\[6pt]
&=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k}k!\\[6pt]
&=np_n.
\end{align}
That is,
$$p_{n+1}=np_n+q_{n+1}.\tag{1}$$
Second,
\begin{align}q_{n+1}-p_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2k!-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k}k!\\[6pt]
&=n!+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\left(\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-1}{k}\right)k!\\[6pt]
&=n!+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}k!\\[6pt]
&=n!+n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}^2(k-1)!\\[6pt]
&=n!+n\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-1}{k}^2k!\\[6pt]
&=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}^2k!\\[6pt]
&=nq_n.\end{align}
That is,
$$q_{n+1}=p_n+nq_n.\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, it follows by induction that 
$$a_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}.\tag{3}$$ Indeed, $(3)$ holds for $n=1$. Assuming $(3)$ holds for a given $n$, it also holds for $n+1$ in place of $n$:
$$a_{n+1}=1+\frac{na_n}{n+a_n}=1+\frac{np_n}{p_n+nq_n}=1+\frac{p_{n+1}-q_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}=\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}.$$
This answers the second part of the OP's question. More precisely, it would also be desirable to prove that $\gcd(p_n,q_n)=1$, but I have not verified this.

**Added 1.** I can now prove that $\gcd(p_n,q_n)=1$, i.e., the fraction $(3)$ is in lowest terms. Let us proceed by induction. For $n=1$, the statement is clear. We assume therefore that $\gcd(p_n,q_n)=1$ for a given $n$, and we prove that $\gcd(p_{n+1},q_{n+1})=1$. If this is not the case, then there is a prime $\ell$ that divides both $p_{n+1}$ and $q_{n+1}$. From $(1)$ we get $\ell\mid np_n$, hence from $(2)$ we get $\ell\mid n^2 q_n$. As $p_n$ and $q_n$ are relatively prime by the induction hypothesis, this forces $\ell\mid n$, and then from $(2)$ we get $\ell\mid p_n$. However,
$$p_n=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k}k!=1+n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{n-1}{k}(k-1)!\ ,$$
whence $p_n\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, and therefore $p_n\equiv 1\pmod{\ell}$. This contradiction shows that $\gcd(p_{n+1},q_{n+1})=1$, and we are done.

**Added 2.** I can now answer the remaining first part of the question. Briefly, as pointed out by მამუკა ჯიბლაძე in a comment, the observed "property of $a$" is equivalent to the identity
$$e E_1(1)=[1/1,1,1/2,1,1/3,1,1/4,1,1/5,1,\dots],$$
where (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral))
$$E_1(x):=\int_x^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt,\qquad x>0.$$
More generally, it is known that (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral))
$$e^x E_1(x)=[x/1,1,x/2,1,x/3,1,x/4,1,x/5,1,\dots].$$